# Twitter Bootstrap and Snap.js

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, snap.js

I'm trying to integrate jakiestfu's [Snap.js](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js) with Twitter Bootstrap.
I've got something that functions (I can get the content to slide, or open a drawer via a click event).  However, I'm at the limit of my CSS skills for the final problem:  The drawer content is always visible regardless of the state of the drawer.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/HJDwx/1/)

While I could hard-code the visibility of the drawer element on document load and do something on the open/close click event, that doesn't do anything for the drag capability that Snap.js has.

```
addEvent(document.getElementById('open-left'), 'click', function () {
// Muck with visibility in here
// Added code sample because StackOverflow wants it with a fiddle...
if (snapper.state().state == "left") {
    snapper.close();
} else {
    snapper.open('left');
}});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup a background color for your content:

```
#content{
    background: white;
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/ygm3L/